# Embedding sound files into beamer presentation with media9

Tags: beamer, inline, media9

I'm trying to embed a sound file inline into a beamer so i don't need to carry the sound file around with the pdf.

Currently I place sound files into my beamer with the multimedia package and this command:

```
\movie[inlinesound]{\fbox{Play}}{igottafever.wav}
```

For some reason the `\sound` command gives scrambled static. But the `inlinesound` option apparently doesn't work with `\movie`. QUESTION 1: Is there some inline option for `\movie`?

All the examples I see with media9 are of audio streams from online.  QUESTION 2: How do I place a local file into a pdf with media9?
This is not working:

```
\includemedia[flashvars={source=igottafever.wav}]{\fbox{Play}}{APlayer.swf
```

Throws an Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file://PDFMedia022077/invalid in Acrobat X

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This site works best if you ask one question at the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only sound file format that can be played back is `mp3`. To embed local resource files (a sound file in the present case) into the PDF, use option `addresource` and adjust the `source` FlashVar accordingly.

Embedded sound file example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
%\usepackage[english]{babel} % no longer required as of media9-20120412 (v0.4)

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Sound example}
\includemedia[
  addresource=igottafever.mp3,
  flashvars={
    source=igottafever.mp3
   &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\fbox{Play}}{APlayer.swf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What will be played, an mp3 file or swf file ? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @truthseeker APlayer is the App, `igottafever.mp3` the media it will play. And Flash Player is the VM in which the App runs.