# problem with \sound

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I'm trying to make a single pdf with `beamer` and a sound file.

The command `\movie` and `\sound` do a good job while the sound file is in the same folder, but

```
\sound[inlinesound]{PLAY}{soundfile.mp3}
```

doesn't work... that is, I make the pdf file with the soundfile in the same folder, the pdf works fine, but if I move the pdf file alone to another folder, then the sound is not there anymore, unlike the `beamer`'s manual :(

Is this a `beamer`'s problem or I'm not reading the manual carefully? How can I produce a single pdf file containing the sound?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Should this be helpful for you?: [Embedding sound files into beamer presentation with media9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51637/152550) In that case, it would be a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I saw that post, I tried to do that (copy and paste the text with obvious filename Chang es, also I tried some other possible modifications ) but I had no success...